# functional testing routes with a https constraint

Tags: testing, ssl, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If I wrap my SSL required routes in a block like this:

```
scope :protocol => "https://", :constraints => { :protocol => 
"https://" } do 
  resources :users, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update] 
end
```

then all my functional tests that reference those routes are now 
spitting out RoutingErrors.  Something like this:

```
put :update, :id => 123 
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches 
{:id=>"123", :controller=>"users", :action=>"update"}
```

FWIW:

```
rake routes | grep update 
user PUT    /users/:id(.:format) 
{:protocol=>"http://", :action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
```

So, what, I'm supposed to specify the protocol in my functional tests 
now?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn HTTPS on in your test's setup:

```
setup do
  @request.env['HTTPS'] = 'on'
end
```

Or you can change your routes.rb to use http in the test environment:

```
scope :constraints => { :protocol => Rails.env.test? "http" : "https" } do 
  resources :users, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update] 
end
```